# Live actions in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

How can we implement live actions in ember without reload or pressing an action button?

for example, if I'm filling a form to change the password, 
In the confirm password input, I need to check the matching of these two passwords lively(without pressing any button)
This is just a case? 
how can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/c1a5d04aae300b57420d604ef07fdfbd?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C) or [gist](https://gist.github.com/henryw14/c1a5d04aae300b57420d604ef07fdfbd). There's plenty of different approaches.

1). Bind an action to the `oninput` event of two input fields

```
<input value={{password2}} oninput={{action 'setPassword2' value="target.value"}} />
<input value={{passwordConfirm2}} oninput={{action 'setPasswordConfirm2' value="target.value"}} />
```

with custom action handlers that invoke a function on input:

```
actions: {
  setPassword2(val){
    this.set('password2', val);
    this.updatePasswordsMatch2();
  },
  setPasswordConfirm2(val){
    this.set('passwordConfirm2', val);
    this.updatePasswordsMatch2();
  }
},
updatePasswordsMatch2(){
  this.set('passwordsMatch2', this.get('password2') === this.get('passwordConfirm2'));   
}
```

2). Same as above but use `onchange` if you only want the event to fire on blur + change

3). 2way binding (old school ember way) with computed properties observing both the password and the confirm:

```
passwordsMatch: computed('password', 'passwordConfirm', function(){
   return this.get('password') === this.get('passwordConfirm'); 
})
```